# Derivative of $\log(\log)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want the derivative of $\frac{d\left(\log(-\frac{1}{2}\log(p))\right)}{dp}$

Is this correct?
$$\left(\log(-\frac{1}{2}\log(p))\right)'=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}\log(p)}\frac{1}{p}=\frac{-2}{p\log(p)}$$

If not Can someone expand on the correct way?

Comment: this is not correct

Comment: the result is $$\frac{1}{p\log(p)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can you kindly show in an answer how to do this? And what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule we get:
$$\left(\log\left(-\frac{1}{2}\log(p)\right)\right)'=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}\log(p)} \left(-\frac{1}{2} \log(p) \right)'=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{2}\log(p)} \left(-\frac{1}{2p}\right)=\frac{1}{p\log(p)}$$

You applied the chain rule incorrectly. There you should differentiate the whole "inner" function $-\frac{1}{2} \log(p)$ and not simply $\log(p)$.